# How generate PDF with RichTextBox data (Text + Image ) in C# Application

Tags: wpf, pdf-generation, richtextbox, rtf

I have a richTextBox in wpf Application, which have Text + Image

I want to generate PDF with RichtextBox which display both Text and Images of RichTextBox

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476636/edit-and-render-richtext

Answer (score 0):

Here are some questions that are more or less the same question. Note the Document property of the RichTextBox is a FlowDocument.

[WPF: flowdocument to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334711/wpf-flowdocument-to-pdf)

[What's the best way to convert a FlowDocument into PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182137/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-flowdocument-into-pdf)

[How to save the content of flowDocument in PDF and Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349490/how-to-save-the-content-of-flowdocument-in-pdf-and-word)